# Internet on Ubuntu 10.04 not working after installing updates on Update Manager

Tags: update-manager, internet

Recently, I was told that I was suppose to install the suggested updates on Update Manager, so I did. Since I usually ignore the Update Manager, it took a long time to install everything. After I restarted my PC, I notice the Internet connection wasn't working. I tried to remove some of the packages I installed earlier but that didn't work. I also tried to upgrade my computer to Ubuntu 12.04 but they said I couldn't because I don't have Internet access. It's been a day and still no connection to the Internet on my PC. 
Please help me, if you have any solutions.

Thank you.

Comment: Could you open a terminal (press Ctrl+Alt+T) and type `nm-tool; lspci`; and then edit the output into your question? Any more information about the make/model of the wireless card could really help as well.

Answer (score 1):

This is one of those, it could be a million different things sorts of problems.  Step one is to see how your NIC is configured.  Try running:

```
ifconfig -a
```

What you will get looks something like this:

```
eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:15:17:12:9a:d6
          inet addr:10.0.0.33  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::215:17ff:fe12:9ad6/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:262459016 errors:0 dropped:432 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:388373760 errors:158 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:158
          collisions:178 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:94742468374 (94.7 GB)  TX bytes:464252544891 (464.2 GB)
          Interrupt:16 Memory:f0800000-f0820000
```

Look for the inet addr, mask, and particularly that it says, "UP".  Post these values and we can work from there.

Comment: Thank you
And I'm sorry but how do you run "ifconfig -a" ?